# Java Servlet hangs on loading Angular static files

Tags: javascript, java, angular, servlets

I have a Java Servlet application that is used for an API and to server my Angular application. I build the Angular application into my `/webapp` folder by running `ng b`. My web.xml config looks like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>html-mapping</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>html-mapping</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The issue happens seemingly randomly where the servlet will hang on loading certain es5 static files. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using?   ng build --prod

Comment: @rickz yes i have tried doing this, yielding the same result.